# Passing an array as a parameter to another function in C

Tags: arrays, c, clion

I fairly new to C and am currently trying to use some parameters from one function in another function.
Essentially from function1 (which asks the user to input an array and return its size) I need to pass the whole array and its size as parameters to function2 which will then print them out to screen/file in the format shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSxKo.png).

How can I create another separate function that uses the array and size of function1 in order to give me the desired output as described above.

For reference, this is the code for function1:

(I made use of a header as these two functions will later on be implemented into a menu)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "function1.h"

//Main
int main(void) // Without the explicit "void" argument list, this isn't a full function definition
{
    int size;
    printf("The size of list: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &size) != 1 || size < 1) { // You should ALWAYS check the return value of a scanf call
        printf("Invalid size input.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int marks[size]; // Need to specify the size and note that you cannot initialize a VLA

    if (size >= 200) {
        printf(" Limit exceeded.\n");
        return 2;
    }
    intarray(marks,size);
    return 0;

}
```

And the header file for function1 is:

```
#ifndef FUNCTION1_H
#define FUNCTION1_H

int intarray(int ar[], int size){

    printf("Please enter %d values:\n"); // You need to give "size" as an argument
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &ar[i]); // You should add a check for valid input here, as I have done in main

    }
    printf("Elements in array are: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d, ", ar[i]);

    }
    
    printf("\n");
    printf("Size of array is: %d", size);

}
#endif //FUNCTION1_H
```

Comment: Placing function *definitions* in headers is a bad idea. Headers should contain declarations only.

Comment: if i understand right, you need to call secont function in first function so you can send the array into it, or in main you can call first function and return the created array and send it to the secont function

Comment: And if you still do include definitions in headers then make these self-contained! This means in this case including `stdio.h` for the `printf` function.

Comment: @EugeneSh. i will edit that and update the code, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Off-topic: Correct type for specifying array sizes is `size_t` (from `stddef.h`), not `int`...

Comment: Checking `size > 200` is a good idea, but you need to do it before `int marks[size]` if you want to avoid errors.

Comment: Off-topic again: If you just want to output a single character `putchar` is much more efficient (`putchar('\n');`) – or in given case include the line break into the subsequent format string: `printf("\nSize ...");`.

Comment: `main()` can pass the array to `intarray()` and then pass the same array to the new function. Arrays are not passed by value. (1) The parameter `int ar[]` in `intarray` is adjusted to `int *ar`. (2) The argument `marks` in the call `intarray(marks, size);` is converted to a pointer to the initial element of the array. (1) and (2) together make it *appear* as though array parameters are passed by reference, although that is an illusion because C does not really have array parameters.